# Media Player not moving seek bar when fast forwarding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, media-player

So I am having this small issue, where the seek bar is not being moved forward when the user taps on the fast forward or rewind buttons on the native iOS controller.

See video
https://youtu.be/CJP131GpSYI

The section of code that makes it possible is printed below.

```
func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
   // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    let changePlaybackPositionCommand = commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand
    changePlaybackPositionCommand.isEnabled = true
    changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget { event in
            let seconds = (event as? MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent)?.positionTime ?? 0
            let time = CMTime(seconds: seconds, preferredTimescale: 1)
            self.player?.seek(to: time)
            return .success
        }
    
    let skipBackwardCommand = commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand
    if(MusicPlayer.mediatype == "podcast")
    {
    skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = true
    }
    else{
        skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = false
    }
    skipBackwardCommand.preferredIntervals = [NSNumber(value: 10)]
    skipBackwardCommand.addTarget(handler: skipBackward)
  
   
    let skipForwardCommand = commandCenter.skipForwardCommand
    if(MusicPlayer.mediatype == "podcast")
    {
    skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = true
    }
    else{
        skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = false
    }
    skipForwardCommand.addTarget(handler: skipForward)
   
    
    
    // Add handler for Play Command
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 0.0 {
            self.player?.play()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

    // Add handler for Pause Command
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 1.0 {
            self.player?.pause()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

    
    
    
    func skipBackward(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
  
        //self.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: -30), preferredTimescale: 1))
       // print(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!)) //Output: 42
        
        //print(event.interval)
        self.player!.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: -30), preferredTimescale: 1))

        
        return .success
       
    }

    func skipForward(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
       self.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: 30), preferredTimescale: 1))
        return .success
    }
    

}
```

Full Media Player code:

```
import SwiftUI
//import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit

struct NowPlayingData: Codable , Identifiable  {
  var id,artist,song,cover:String

  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case id = "_id", artist , song , cover
  }
}

class MusicPlayer {
static let shared = MusicPlayer()
static var mediatype = ""
static var artist = ""
static var song = ""
static var cover = ""
static var urls = ""
static var dur = 0
static var uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString


var player: AVPlayer?
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

    
    
    
    func gettype(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void){
          
            completion(MusicPlayer.mediatype)
       
      }
      
      func getPodCastPlayerNP(completion: @escaping (NowPlayingData) -> ()) {
       // Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 15, repeats: true) { (timer) in
          let songdata = "{\"_id\": \"1\",\"song\": \"\(MusicPlayer.song)\",\"artist\": \"\(MusicPlayer.artist)\", \"cover\": \"\(MusicPlayer.cover)\"}"
          let data: Foundation.Data = songdata.data(using: .utf8)!
          
          let podcast = try! JSONDecoder().decode(NowPlayingData.self, from: data)
                
                         //print(data!)
                        // let episode = podcast.programs
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                            // The array is stored under programs now
                          //print(podcast)
                          completion(podcast)
                        }
         // }
      }

    func startBackgroundMusic(url: String, type:String) {
     
        MusicPlayer.mediatype = String(type)
        
        //let urlString = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"
        let urlString = url+"?uuid="+MusicPlayer.uuid!
        print(urlString)
        guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString) else { return }

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
        
      
        do {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.duckOthers, .defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
           // defaults.set("1", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
          //  defaults.set("0", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            print(error)
        }

         #if targetEnvironment(simulator)

        self.playerViewController.player = player
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        print("SIMULATOR")

         #else

        self.setupRemoteTransportControls()
        player?.play()

        #endif
        

    }
    
    
    func startBackgroundMusicTwo() {

        
        let urlString = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"
        //let urlString = url
        guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString) else { return }

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
        
      
        do {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.duckOthers, .defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
           // defaults.set("1", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
          //  defaults.set("0", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            print(error)
        }

         #if targetEnvironment(simulator)

        self.playerViewController.player = player
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        print("SIMULATOR")

         #else

        self.setupRemoteTransportControls()
        player?.play()

        #endif

    }




func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
   // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    let changePlaybackPositionCommand = commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand
    changePlaybackPositionCommand.isEnabled = true
    changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget { event in
            let seconds = (event as? MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent)?.positionTime ?? 0
            let time = CMTime(seconds: seconds, preferredTimescale: 1)
            self.player?.seek(to: time)
            return .success
        }
    
    let skipBackwardCommand = commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand
    if(MusicPlayer.mediatype == "podcast")
    {
    skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = true
    }
    else{
        skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = false
    }
    skipBackwardCommand.preferredIntervals = [NSNumber(value: 10)]
    skipBackwardCommand.addTarget(handler: skipBackward)
  
   
    let skipForwardCommand = commandCenter.skipForwardCommand
    if(MusicPlayer.mediatype == "podcast")
    {
    skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = true
    }
    else{
        skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = false
    }
    skipForwardCommand.addTarget(handler: skipForward)
   
    
    
    // Add handler for Play Command
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 0.0 {
            self.player?.play()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

    // Add handler for Pause Command
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 1.0 {
            self.player?.pause()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

    
    
    
    func skipBackward(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
  
        //self.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: -30), preferredTimescale: 1))
       // print(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!)) //Output: 42
        
        //print(event.interval)
        self.player!.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: -30), preferredTimescale: 1))

        
        return .success
       
    }

    func skipForward(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
       self.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: 30), preferredTimescale: 1))
        return .success
    }
    

}
    
    
    
    func nowplaying(with artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork, artist: String, song: String, duration: Int){
  
        
        if(duration == 0){
            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
                  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:song,
                  MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:artist,
                  MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
                  MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: true
            ]
        }
        else{

            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
                  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:song,
                  MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:artist,
                  MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
                  MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: false,
                  MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: duration,
                  MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1.0,
                  MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!)
                  
            ]
        }

   // self.getArtBoard();
}


func setupNowPlayingInfo(with artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork) {
      MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
           MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Some name",
           MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Some name",
           MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
           //MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration),
           //MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1,
           //MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())
       ]
   }



func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            completion(UIImage(data:data))
        }
    })
        .resume()
}

    func getArtBoard(artist: String, song: String, cover: String, urls: String, duration: Int) {
   // MusicPlayer.JN = "[{'artist': \(artist), 'song':\(song), 'cover': \(cover)}]"
    MusicPlayer.artist = artist
    MusicPlayer.song = song
    MusicPlayer.cover = cover
    MusicPlayer.urls = urls
    
    
    guard let url = URL(string: cover) else { return }
    getData(from: url) { [weak self] image in
        guard let self = self,
            let downloadedImage = image else {
                return
        }
        let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: downloadedImage.size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
            return downloadedImage
        })
        self.nowplaying(with: artwork, artist: artist, song: song, duration: duration)
    }
}



    func stopBackgroundMusic() {
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.pause()

}
}
```

Full GitHub code:
https://github.com/redimongo/iOS-Radio-App

Comment: Did you tried my `git` code mate?

Comment: as i mentioned in previous question i shared you controller coding and it works properly if you see that.

Comment: @RB's I could not get the git working.

Comment: okay no problem.

Comment: never share you full code with anyone it must be copied your app that'w why i told to remove.

Comment: @RB's all good.

Comment: check video it's working for me https://youtu.be/HEsyGXjZCiY

Comment: That is a video player not an audio player - and also am looking at the lock screen seekbar / CarPlay seeker / notification section seekbar. @RB's

Comment: let me check for lock screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232157/discussion-between-rbs-and-russellharrower).

Answer (score 0):

```
        func skipBackward(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
            
            //self.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: -30), preferredTimescale: 1))
            // print(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!)) //Output: 42
            
            //print(event.interval)
            //self.player!.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: -30), preferredTimescale: 1))
            let currentTime = self.player?.currentTime()
            self.player?.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: currentTime!.seconds - 30, preferredTimescale: 1), completionHandler: { isCompleted in
                if isCompleted {
                }
            })
            return .success
            
        }
        
        func skipForward(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
            //self.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: 30), preferredTimescale: 1))
            let currentTime = self.player?.currentTime()
            self.player?.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: currentTime!.seconds + 30, preferredTimescale: 1), completionHandler: { isCompleted in
                if isCompleted {
                }
            })
            return .success
        }
```

Change this 2 function with above code and let me know. what you face here.

Comment: It still is not updating the seeker -  but is moving the audio forward 30 seconds.

Comment: seek bar is not moving?. let me check.

Comment: That is correct correct say I fast forward at 2 seconds into the audio clip, when it skips to 32 seconds the seek bar still says 2 seconds.

Comment: don't do that @RussellHarrower never share you full code please delete link from question and from and comments.